# ODIN - Error <ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed

Tags: rooting, twrp, odin, android-10

I am currently trying to root an `android 10` device (a samsung sm-j600f) using `ODIN 3.14.1` and `TWRP`but when I hit the start button I get `<ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed.` error. The whole error message is as below:

```
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1401)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> Total Binary size: 25 M
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/004> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/004> recovery.img
<ID:0/004> RQT_CLOSE !!
<ID:0/004> 
<ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

I have tried using different cables and different TWRP and ODIN versions but none helped. The TWRP and ODIN versions I used are as follows:

- ODIN v3.14.1
- ODIN v3.13.3
- TWRP-3.2.3-j6ltedx-unofficial
- TWRP-3.2.3-TwrpBuilder-j6ltedx-2018-08-21_14-15

Also, I have enabled OEM unlock and USB Debugging modes as well.

What could be the reason behind the problem? All help will be appreciated.

Comment: I also saw that TWRP might not be supporting Android 10 devices yet actually. [link](https://twrp.me/site/update/2019/10/23/twrp-and-android-10.html). But still trying other ways like installing it using ADB fastboot etc.

Comment: I have a OnePlus 7 on 10 and it's long had official TWRP., so that may not be true always. Better to check developer forums on XDA//I am not familiar with Samsung devices but if it's just to root, you don't need TWRP, isn't it? You can do with Magisk by patching boot image

Comment: It is actually just for root. I thought I needed TWRP and above steps for that. That would be great if you can tell the steps to follow for rooting an android 10 device. Currently I am trying to use ADB fastboot but it doesn't work either. I get tons of errors.

Comment: Posted a self answered question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232257/131553).