# How do you root a device with Magisk when it doesn't have a custom recovery

Tags: rooting, magisk, python, android-11, google-pixel-4a

This is a self answered question to address the subject of title.

With a recovery in place, rooting with Magisk is straightforward,it gets a tad difficult when you don't have a recovery.This was vaguely addressed in [Stock image dump for running Magisk necessary?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200113/stock-image-dump-for-running-magisk-necessary/200114#comment306071_200114).

So, I thought of making a self answered question to

- Help those who don't know and
- Add to  canonical questions. It's important for our site to have such questions as easy reference (not-so-subtle request to others to post more self answered questions!).

**Notes:**

1. I have tried both Linux and Android versions of the answer and they work fine (tested on Pixel 4a, Android 11). The process *may* look daunting but it isn't (I know nothing about Linux, yet managed to root without issues).
2. Moderators are free to make this a community wiki, if more answers are posted depending on the device variants :)

Comment: for samsung devices just use [samloader](https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy) ([support thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-samloader-samfirm-frija-replacement.4105929/unread?new=1)) and patch the whole *AP\*.tar.md5* with Magisk Manager (no TWRP needed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you happen to have a PIXEL device then [Pixel Flasher](https://github.com/badabing2005/PixelFlasher/releases/tag/v5.3.3.0) , an open source project can do everything below, real easy-easy. For help on interface, see [here](https://github.com/badabing2005/PixelFlasher)

This tool apparently works for some One Plus devices, YMMV

---

This answer is **not** applicable to Samsung / Huawei devices

---

- First, unlock your bootloader. This again ranges from very easy to complicated procedures getting unlock codes, waiting period etc, so read that up first and you have [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) installed (this would help , if you don't have it [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/131553)).
- Second, and **very important** read these [installation instructions](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html) from Magisk Developer before proceeding. There are many variants of device architectures and OEM specific issues.
- Third, read **above  step thoroughly** and accept outcome of your actions. Especially, Samsung /Huawei users, see respective linked sections.
- Fourth, this answer is applicable to devices having

  - boot ramdisk in which case you need a copy of the `boot.img` (in which case custom recovery if available can also be used, but then we are assuming it isn't available)
  - If your device does NOT have boot ramdisk, you need a copy of the `recovery.img`
    ( To verify, install Magisk Manager and check `SAR`, as explained in official Magisk instructions, linked in second bullet point or read up the forums in XDA to figure out).
- Substitute `recovery.img` for `boot.img`, if your device doesn't have ramdisk. Answer talks of `boot.img` as an example but they are interchangeable as far as process is concerned.
- This process works on all  Android versions, including 11. I did it on my Pixel 4a running Android 11 (on earlier versions, my devices had custom recovery, so I didn't need this).

## Extracting boot image (or recovery)

- Get the **official firmware package or OTA files** from official firmware packages, your custom ROM zip (if using one), or go to [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) and seek for resources, guides, discussions, or ask for help in your device’s forum.
- Pick up the firmware or *full OTA* (*not* incremental OTA) file that corresponds to the Android security update of your device , not necessarily the latest (you never know if the `boot.img` has been changed).
- Prior to A/B partition system implementation ,these update firmware/ OTA packages came with partition images, which could easily be extracted and used for manual flashing. But now, these update packages come with a single `Payload.bin` file that contains the individual partition images (`boot.img` or `recovery.img`).
- There are many blogs that tell you how to this. I found [How to Extract Android OTA Payload.bin File using Payload Dumper Tool on a PC or Android Device](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/how-to-extract-android-payload-bin-file/) to be very comprehensive and clear.

This shows how you can extract the boot image using a Linux machine, Android or Windows.I don't intend copy pasting the article with photos in it's entirety, but all essential steps are listed.

**Using Payload Dumper Tool to Extract `Payload.bin`**

- Payload Dumper tool is basically a Python script/program created by developer [ius](https://github.com/ius) that allows users to easily extract  `Payload.bin`

**Installing Payload Dumper tool**

**On laptop (Windows/ Linux)**

1. The tool requires Python 3 or above, which can be downloaded from the [official page](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. When installing Python, make sure that it’s added to the PATH on your PC. For Windows PC, this could be easily done by checking the `Add Python to PATH` option within the installer. For Linux/macOS, you can use the instructions provided on [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_environment.htm).
3. Download the latest version of the Payload Dumper Tool on your PC from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QpsywAbNroDKEDz4TytQl8UlK6v2gJSi/view) and extract its contents to a suitable location. Upon extracting you should have a new folder named `payload_dumper`.
4. Open the command-line window on your PC in the `payload_dumper` folder, where the tool and the payload.bin files are present. To do this:

- On a Windows PC: Hold the SHIFT key and right-click on an empty space inside the folder, then select the `Open PowerShell window here` option.
- On a macOS/Linux PC: Launch the Terminal and change its directory to the `payload_dumper` folder using the `cd` command. For example: If the `payload_dumper` folder is located in the `Documents` directory, then the command should look like: `cd Documents/payload_dumper`

5. In order to use the tool on your PC, you must first install ‘Protobuf‘ (Google’s data interchange format) which is basically a dependency. To install it, enter the following command.

   - On Windows (in PowerShell): `python -m pip install protobuf`
   - On Linux/macOS (in Terminal): `python3 -m pip install protobuf`
6. Now to finally extract the Android OTA payload.bin file, first,extract the downloaded ZIP file to your PC . The extracted contents will include the “Payload.bin” file, which is what you’d need to extract. Copy the Payload.bin file inside the “payload_dumper” folder. Next,enter the following command.

   - On Windows (in PowerShell): `python payload_dumper.py payload.bin`
   - On Linux/macOS (in Terminal):`python3 payload_dumper.py payload.bin`
7. The tool will now start extracting the individual partition images from the Payload.bin file. Once finished, you will find the extracted files inside the same `payload_dumper` folder and you can pick up the `boot.img` or `recovery.img`

**On Android**. This is a little slower but also saves one step as you would see later.

1. Download the Payload Dumper Tool from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QpsywAbNroDKEDz4TytQl8UlK6v2gJSi/view?usp=sharing). Once downloaded, extract the contents of the `payload_dumper_tool_by_ius.zip` file to the root of your phone’s internal storage. You could extract it anywhere, however, the root directory is more convenient. The extracted ‘payload_dumper’ folder will contain the tool’s Python scripts
2. Now, download the  full OTA / firmware package from which you want to extract the firmware images. Once downloaded, extract the  package on your device to get the `payload.bin` file. Then copy the extracted `payload.bin` file inside the ‘payload_dumper’ folder that you extracted during step 1 above.
3. Download and install the [Termux](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) app (a Terminal Emulator, avoid the Play Store version as it is not updated) on your Android device. Once installed, launch the app from your phone’s app drawer.
4. Install and set up Python on your Android device. To do this, enter the following commands in Termux *one after the other*:

   `pkg install python -y`

   `pip install --upgrade pip`

   `pip install protobuf`

   `apt update && apt upgrade -y`
5. Now, use the following command to grant storage permissions to ‘Termux’: `termux-setup-storage`. As soon as you enter the command, you’ll see a prompt to “Allow Termux to access photos, media and files on your device”.  Simply press “Allow” to grant the permissions.
6. Change Termux’s directory to the “payload_dumper” folder using the following command, provided that you have the folder placed on the root of your phone’s internal storage.

   `cd storage/shared/payload_dumper`
7. Finally, enter the following command in Termux to extract the Android OTA Payload.bin bile on your Android device: `python payload_dumper.py payload.bin`

Once finished, the extracted firmware images will be placed inside the same ‘payload_dumper’ tool.

You are nearly done!

## Last step of [patching images](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html)

(from the official Magisk instructions)

> - Copy the boot/recovery image to your device (*this step not needed if you used Android method*)
> - *Download the latest stable Magisk apk from the [official source](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk) and install on your device (grant permission for installing from other sources)*
> - Press the Install button in the Magisk card
> - If you are patching a recovery image, make sure “Recovery Mode” is checked in options. In most cases it should already be automatically checked.
> - Choose “Select and Patch a File” in method, and select the stock boot/recovery image
> - Magisk Manager will patch the image to `[Internal Storage]/Download/magisk_patched.img`.
> - Copy the patched image to your PC with ADB:
>   `adb pull /sdcard/Download/magisk_patched.img`
> - Flash the patched boot/recovery image to your device.
> - For most devices, reboot into fastboot mode and flash with command:
>   `fastboot flash boot /path/to/magisk_patched.img` or
>   `fastboot flash recovery /path/to/magisk_patched.img` if flashing a recovery image
> - Reboot and voila!

(Text in Italics added)

For any issue with Magisk, you will find [this guide](https://www.didgeridoohan.com/magisk/Homepage) by [Didgeridoohan](https://forum.xda-developers.com/m/didgeridoohan.4667597/) very handy.

Comment: Some devices need additional step [disable AVB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231168/do-i-need-a-vbmeta-parititon-to-install-gsi) from fastboot. Magisk does patch [vbmeta](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221756/what-is-02-in-the-magisk-patched-vbmeta-img) by default when installed from TWRP, but not every device have [vbmeta](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image) partition

Comment: For the HTC U Play, I couldn't find a way to extract boot.img (from the rather hard to find "stock" images), as it was a .zip with more .zips inside, no boot.img.  I ended up booting in twrp with fastboot (after unlocking bootloader using htcdev.com website), making a backup, and passing the boot.win to Magisk.

Comment: For users on Android 12: Payload dumper tool is broken on Linux (as of today, at least for Pixel 4a images, IDK why ). I resorted to Android method which works fine