# Undoing MagiskHide or updating magisk without the GUI (perhaps by using magisk --install-module)?

Tags: root-access, magisk, root-cloak

I have magisk installed on my phone – binary & daemon version 22.0:MAGISK (22000). It is great. I had to install MagiskHide to enable a banking app that otherwise did not work.

I used the option to rename the MagiskManager binary to something else to prevent it from being detected – which was required for the (evil!) banking app to work. I now wish to update Magisk and install another framework. Unfortunately, whilst I can see the renamed binary to the gui / UI on my launcher, if I tap on it, it doesn't open – the shortcuts to "Modules" and "su" and so forth are still there, but the binary doesn't work.

If I log in via adb shell, I can call `su` and all works that way. Other apps that rely upon root don't show the permissions dialogue if I did not previously authorise them – unfortunately, because I updated `termux`, that includes it and su just hangs.

In a root shell, `magisk` and `magiskhide` all work – I have disabled magiskhide but still cannot open the manager application.

If I install the latest version of Magisk from github, it cannot connect to the daemon and offers to flash an image.

I am therefore in a bit of a pickle. I would like to know:

– Can you run `magisk --install-module <path_to_latest_magisk.zip>` to get it to update itself? Would that bring the gui back?
– If not, can I manually undo whatever magiskhide did to rename or hide the MagiskManager gui?

One option I have yet to try is flashing the latest magisk zip via twrp but I am slightly worried that having two versions of magisk is likely to be a BadThing™...

EDIT: Here's what the (renamed) Magisk Manager binary looks like – none of the buttons work and nothing appears in `dmesg` when I tap them:

[image: unhappy magisk]

Comment: Related/possibly duplicate https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231184/131553

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232411/131553

Comment: @beeshyams – thanks for your replies. What do you mean by clearing the data – I haven't wiped the whole phone; `pm list packages` shows no magisk anywhere and I do not have it installed. I've tried installing and uninstalling the latest apk of magisk, but to no avail.

Comment: Oh OK..I misunderstood.. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it transpired that `MagiskHide` had successfully hidden Magisk from itself. I:

1. Logged in via `adb shell` and got root
2. Ran `magiskhide disable`
3. Uninstalled the stub app shown below
4. Downloaded the current magisk .apk from the github repo
5. Rebooted (normally) and installed it
6. Found that magically my previous version of magisk was detected, and I could thus update it.

Phew!