# How to root Redmi 9C (Redmi 9 India)?

Tags: rooting, xiaomi, magisk, redmi, systemless-root

As I understand I can get root access without installing a custom recovery with fastboot commands as described in the [Magisk Installation Instructions](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html).

I have downloaded the Magisk app and under Ramdisk I do get a yes.

[image: Screenshot of Magisk Manager]

The name of the device is indeed cattail which I have confirmed by running

> adb shell

in my terminal, screenshot posted:

[image: adb shell]

However I came across [this XDA forum post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-via-magisk-doesnt-work.4168263/) where it wasn't possible to get root access with Magisk and fastboot.

[This post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-root-xiaomi-redmi-9c-functional.4200183/) appears to offer a solution but upon a little digging it seems that the instruction provided here cater to the device "angelica" but not cattail.

Here is how I found out it was angelica: In the screenshot provided in the forum, you can see model name of the device is:

> M2006C3MG

while the model name of my phone is:

> M2006C3MII

Upon searching the different model names on the internet, it is quite obvious that device is different from mine.

So here are my questions:

## 1. Where should I download the firmware from to extract the relevant boot.img file?

[1. This link](https://xiaomistockrom.com/xiaomi-redmi-9) or [2. This one](https://xiaomistockrom.com/xiaomi-redmi-9c). I am confused because I had bought the Redmi 9 India (from Amazon) but apparently cattail is Redmi 9C. The first link(for Redmi 9) has an option having India while the second one(for Redmi 9C) doesn't.

## 2. How do I even root this device?

I'm unable to properly piece together all the info online and would greatly appreciate any pointers or guides. Searching for "how to root redmi 9 india" gives weird results asking to use Kingo Root and the like.

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/cattail

Comment: This may help with more details re :second part of your question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232257/how-do-you-root-a-device-with-magisk-when-it-doesnt-have-a-custom-recovery

Comment: OK @alecxs. Should I flash the vbmeta then? Is my device not different from the one mentioned in the XDA thread? Or are the model numbers unique for every phone and they are indeed referring to cattail?

Comment: @beeshyams I already know how to root supported devices with fastboot. I've done it successfully in another phone I have which is the Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus (a6020a46) which is 6 years old at this point. I would have gone ahead and done the same on this device had I not had a confusion regarding relevant boot.img file as well as the link I found on XDA.

Comment: rooting steps are identical, devices are not. Do not flash foreign boot.img. vbmeta provided on xda is just empty file and therefore universal

Comment: Hey @alecxs should I download the recovery option's img file or the fastboot option's ? I'm runnign 12.0.10.x .This probably is a dumb question, sorry.

Comment: fastboot download contains all partition images. recovery download should contain desired boot image too. in your case it probably doesn't matter

Comment: okay @alecxs thanks