# How to get root access on Wiko Sunny 2 Plus?

Tags: rooting, 7.0-nougat

I was wondering if it was possible to root Wiko Sunny 2 Plus phone?

I've seen so many guides on how to do this for other devices

Unfortunately typing with the keyword "root" with this phone on youtube nothing appeared to me

Would you give me a way to root this phone?

I tried using applications like KingRoot and KingoRoot but root failed.

As Android version it had: Android 7.0 Nougat

But he had the option to unlock the bootloader

Comment: XDA Forum is usually the best resource for rooting (or in general, tinkering with the) devices. However, looks like the closest thing that exists on XDA is [rooting Wiko Sunny 2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-twrp-wiko-sunny-2-spd7731c-root-process-with-twrp-port-buggy-touch.4081667/) (not Plus) instead.

Comment: So I can't root Wiko Sunny 2 Plus, is that impossible?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I can't answer that. As of its current state, looks like no one has been able to root it, or has not shared the solution publicly. From the XDA forum, some have tested on their Plus devices but got a blocking issue. Probably the custom recovery TWRP needs to be ported for this device specifically, which no one seems to have done it.

Comment: if I try to use magisk, without TWRP recovery, by modifying the "boot.img" image from Magisk and flash the modified image? would work? I wrote a guide on Word

Comment: For Magisk approach, then [How do you root a device with Magisk when it doesn't have a custom recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232257/44325) might possibly help. However, looks like it's still not guaranteed to work on every device.

Comment: Here I sent a guide written in Word [my guide](http://sorecchione07.altervista.org/How_to_get_root_permissions_on_Wiko_Sunny_2_Plus.docx), includes unlocking the bootlaoder, but I haven't tested it yet because I don't have the phone with me, but I think it would work if I tried!   As you said earlier, it may not work on all devices, best try!