# Magisk 25+ on a custom ROM: ramdisk + vbmeta, but no boot.img

Tags: lineageos, magisk, micro-g

According to the release notes in [Magisk v25 there was significant rewrite](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/changes.html). The installation instructions advocated now say flashing Magisk in recovery is

> This installation method is **deprecated and is maintained with minimum effort.** YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED!

Instead they're pushing a new ["Patching Image"](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#patching-images) method.

My device has a `vbmeta` and a ramdisk, but I don't understand what they mean with `boot.img`. What is that?

I'm flashing LineageOS with Micro G, which has

- `lineage-18.1-20220703-microG-instantnoodlep.zip`

There is no boot.img there, and even in the zip there is no `.img`. So how do you get the patched method working with a custom ROM that isn't an `.img`? All the instructions say is

> If your device has boot ramdisk, get a copy of the `boot.img`.

But it doesn't say where to get the `boot.img`?

Comment: [Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232257/131553)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did that worked.

- [Install TWRP](https://twrp.me/oneplus/oneplus8p.html)
- Download [payload-dumper-go](https://github.com/ssut/payload-dumper-go)
- Run `go build`
- For your `lineage` or `lineage-microG` distribution which is a `.zip`, run `unzip MyDownloadedImage.zip`
- Inside you'll have your `payload.bin`, you need to run

  ```
  ./payload-dumper-go ./payload.bin
  ```
- This will output a directory like `extracted_20220713_181918/` inside which you'll have your `magisk_patched-<number>_<hash>.img`

After that you must use `TWRP` to flash the patched image.

1. Push this file over to your phone with

   ```
   adb push ./boot.img /sdcard
   ```
2. Run with `Magisk` and patch that `boot.img`, this will create a new patched file under `Download` as `magisk_patched`. **IT DOES NOT REPLACE THE `boot.img`.**
3. Reboot into TWRP.

   1. Click `Install` (top left)
   2. Click `Install Image` (bottom right)
   3. Browse to `Download` (should be `/sdcard/Download`)
   4. Select the `magisk_patched-<number>_<hash>.img`
   5. Select `Boot`
   6. Swipe to confirm

---

## Not using TWRP?

If you're not using TWRP, you can manually flash `boot`, by

1. Pulling the image down from your phone,

   ```
   adb pull /sdcard/Download/*.img
   ```
2. Flashing with `fastboot`, like

   ```
   fastboot flash boot /sdcard/Download/magisk_patched.img
   ```

Comment: Even if you don't have TWRP, it can be done as explained here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232257/131553