# Rooting issue Xiaomi Mi 9t Pro

Tags: rooting, root-access, xiaomi, android-11

I recently got my hands on a Xiaomi Mi 9t Pro. I tried to root this device using twrp-3.7.0_9-0-raphael and Magisk 26.1 but it doesn't seem to work.

Phone Specs:

1. MIUI-version 12.5.1
2. Android version 11

1st method:

1. Put phone in fastboot and connect to computer.
2. use platform-tools to check and flash recovery twrp to phone and boot it.
3. Format the phone using TWRP
4. Reboot phone in recovery mode using TWRP
5. Drag and drop Magisk.zip and uninstall.zip (same file, different name) to phone from computer.
6. Flash the zip files using TWRP.
7. Reboot the phone and check if Magisk is installed.

**This procedure doesn't seem to work for me.**

I've also tried:

1. On phone, download latest magisk.apk from the official source.
2. Copy and change the magisk.apk to magisk.zip and uninstall.zip using FX file manager.
3. Reboot phone into TWRP.
4. Install the zip file using TWRP.
5. Reboot phone.

**This procedure also does not seem to work because Magisk does not appear on phone.**

I did manage to unlock the bootloader and install TWRP on my device.
Does someone know what I am doing wrong? Does anyone have suggestions? This is my first time rooting a Android phone.

Comment: Can you please add links where you have those tutorials from? Especially the first one looks outdated as nowadays you need the bootloader file of your phone which is then modified by Magisk app (you can simply install magisk apk in Android) and that modified bootloader is then flashed via fastboot. Afterwards Magisk app will get access to root. See original Magisk install tutorial: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the reaction. It's true the tutorials I used are quite old (2020) but these were the only ones I could find. Here's the link -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBLPRRBMjeg. 

I will check if I can find the bootloader file and root my phone that way.

Kind Regards,

Sleek

Comment: You have TWRP but in case you have issues you can try [How do you root a device with Magisk when it doesn't have a custom recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232257/how-do-you-root-a-device-with-magisk-when-it-doesnt-have-a-custom-recovery)

Comment: I managed to successfully root my device thanks to Robert's helpful comment. Unlike my previous attempts with outdated tutorials, following the official Magisk Guidelines made the rooting process incredibly smooth and straightforward.